# Scrapy: TypeError: start_requests() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm starting work on a new scrapy project. So far I have:

```
class ContactSpider(Spider):
    name = "contact"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.domain.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://web.domain.com/DECORATION"
    ]



    def start_requests(self,response):

        l = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="ListingResults"]/text()').extract()
        print(l)
```

I'm getting:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-08-17 12:37:16 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hlib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 163, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 167, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 73, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
exceptions.TypeError: start_requests() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
2016-08-17 12:37:16 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 73, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: start_requests() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-08-17 12:37:16 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start_requests` is a method from `scrapy.spider` it takes no arguments other than `self`. It is used to create starting `Requests` so it should **yield** some `Request` objects(or return a list of `Requests`).

```
def start_requests(self,response):
```

should be:

```
def start_requests(self):
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm confused by the error : "TypeError: start_requests() takes exactly 2 arguments". if you do def start_requests(self): isn't that only one argument?

Comment: @user61629 Yeah, your `start_requests()` expects two arguments: self and response. Now scrapy tries to call **your** `start_request` method with only 1 argument: `self` and it expects two, this is why this error is happening.

Comment: Thanks again, can you tell me how you approach the documentation to find this out?

Comment: You can find docs on `start_requests` here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests You can also see in the traceback that some code is trying: `start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())`. Other than that you can always check `scrapy.Spider` for source code, the whole projects is open source so you can easily check most of it. Though I'd advise to pretty much learn this diagram by heart: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#overview